# WIndows form GUI editor in Monodevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I have written a tool in Visual Studio Community using a C# windows form project. When I started the project I was unaware Microsoft insist on a user signing into an account after 30 days, (even though they offer an offline installation). For security reasons I cannot connect the computer to the internet to login. I have downloaded MonoDevelop and successfully opened and compiled the project. However, I would like to have the ability to "easily" edit the GUI. MonoDevelop's documentation seems to have little in-sight as to if this is possible. I checked out http://www.monodevelop.com/documentation/stetic-gui-designer/ which describes the process for native Mono applications. When I open the Form1.cs file, I am presented only with the option to view the source code. Is it possible to view the GUI designer?

Answer (score 1):

The Stetic GUI Designer is only available for GTK 2.x based applications and not for Windows' Forms.

There is a project called `WinForms Designer` that might help you, it has not been updated for many years, but it still runs on at least OS-X (that is only OS that I have personally used it on).

http://www.mono-project.com/archived/winforms_designer

Note: For OS-X (or Linux) using the latest Mono, you will need to update the `Makefile` and replace the references to `gmcs` to `mcs`